# Is there a way to find the customizing request number for a given record at a maintenance view?

Tags: abap, transport, sap-data-dictionary

In ABAP we can check the latest workbench request assigned to a given code from `Utilities->Versions->Version Management` menu.

Is there any similar feature to check which is the customizing request for a given record at a maintenance view (SM30) ?

ps. of course, considering that the transparent table for that given record have the delivery class E, or C, that needs the customizing request to allow the user to insert or remove the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table entries are transported as R3TR TABU or R3TR VDAT entries, while maintained via SM30. You can find these using function "Search for Objects in Request/Task", which you can find in transactions SE03 or SE09 (as described by Esti). - This way you can find all requests and tasks, which contain any entry from the table or view.

Alternatively you can look directly into DB table to find particular record directly.

You can do it following way:

1. start transaction SE16
2. enter the table name E071K
3. field OBJNAME is your table
4. field TABKEY contains the key of the record
5. execute the selection
6. field TRKORR then contains the request or task you are looking for...

Keep in mind that client-dependent tables start with client, and the key is concatenation of all the fields and it can contain * (star).

Example: for instance the record for company code DE01 in client 055 in table T001 has the tabkey value

```
055DE01
```

For table T001E, to transport all the entries of company code DE01 it would be then

```
055DE01*
```

Comment: Actually this method seems to be more accurate than SE03, specially for standard customizing tables, so that's why I've changed my accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Run Transaction SE03
2. Execute Report: Search for Objects in Request/Task
3. In the object Selections screen enter TABU in a free field in the second column after the checkbox.
4. Enter the table/view name that contains the entries
5. Select the object checkbox next to your new line + the Modifiable checkbox under Request/Task Selection
6. Execute the program

This will return a list of all transport requests that contain entries for this table.

Unfortunately from here you will have to go to each transport separately & check the keys for the entries that was transported